# Proving $(ac \pm bd)^2 + (ad \mp bc)^2$ are the only "sum of two squares" for $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)$

Tags: number-theory

I'd like to know if the only 'sum of two squares' expressions for $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$ are $(ac\pm bd)^2 + (ad\mp bc)^2$. (Expression that works generally for all integers $a, b, c, d$)
It looks pretty true to me since numbers like $(2^2+1^2)(3^2+1^2)=50$ can only be written in the sum of two squares as $(2\times3+1\times1)^2+(2\times1-1\times3)^2=7^2+1^2$ or $(2\times3-1\times1)^2+(2\times1+1\times3)^2=5^2+5^2$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if $a^2+b^2=a'^2+b'^2$? There are numbers which can be written as a sum of squares in multiple ways. Are $a,b$ fixed, or do you varry $a,b$ over all the possibilities?

Comment: @N.S. I don't think we'll take that into account.
It needs to work for all integers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @WillJagy Do you mean because 1105 can be expressed as three different sums of squares? Like $33^2+4^2=31^2+12^2=23^2+24^2=1105$? (Sorry if I missed any)
That's why I'd like to see if 50 is just a special case and there exist other sum-of-square expressions for $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$ or rather 1105 is a special case where more than two expressions exist.

Comment: @WillJagy I edited my question to make it a little clearer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $50$ is "special" because it is $p^2q$ where $p$ and $q$ are  unequal primes, with neither $p$ nor $q$  being congruent to $3$ mod $4.$ ... If $n=p^aq^b r^c$ where  $p,q,r$ are $3$ distinct primes, none congruent to $3$ mod $4,$  and $a,b,c$ are positive integers, than $n$ is a sum of two non-zero squares in at least $3$ ways